# Restore scroll position on back

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have a long page of results. When I click on an item (going on a specific item page) and then go back to the page result it could be very useful to restore the scroll position in result page.
I have 2 ideas I actually don't like:

- add a parameter to the url of the result page like `results?scrollitem=2` (adding `notify:false` to this transition) and then go to the item page.
- using `$cacheFactory` to store the scroll position and then use it.

There is a smarter way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Store the position of the scroll where he was in  $rootScope, but a clean approach would be to store in the scope which is local to the directive where you are redirecting.

I assume that your application is a single page application. If not then 
$cacheFactory can work for you.

Edit : -  please refer this link to understand scope

https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: It's a single page app. I'm not clear with this "store in the scope which is local to the directive where you are redirecting". Which directive are you talking about?

Comment: the directive that you are using to render dom

Comment: I know how the isolated scope works, but since when I leave the result page the scope is destroyed I still don't get your solution..